# Strange array behaviour in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have the following code written for NodeJS:

```
/* server.js */
'use strict';

const http = require('http'),
    url = require('url');
    METHODS = ['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'],
    _routePathIndex = Array.apply(null, Array(METHODS.length)).map(() => {return []}),
    _routeMethodIndex = _routePathIndex.slice(),
    _server = http.createServer();

_server.on('request', (req, res) => {
    let parsed = url.parse(req.url),
        methodIndexVal = METHODS.indexOf(req.method),
        PathIndexVal = _routePathIndex[methodIndexVal].indexOf(parsed.pathname);

    _routeMethodIndex[methodIndexVal][PathIndexVal](req, res);
});

module.exports = _init();

function _init(){
    let rs = { listen: _listen };
    METHODS.forEach( (val,i) => {
        rs[val.toLowerCase()] = function(route, handler){
            _routePathIndex[i].push(route);
            _routeMethodIndex[i].push(handler);
        };
    });

    return rs;
};

function _listen(port, callback){
    _server.listen(port, callback);
}
```

To test this out I have the I have a very simple script:

```
/* server.test.js */
var app = require('./server.js');
app.get('/', (req,res) => { console.log(req, res); });
app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('listening at port', 3000) });
```

The strangeness begins on line 2 of server.test.js which executes the following code block in server.js, I added the comments to display the values of both `_routePathIndex` and `_routeMethodIndex`.

```
...
        rs[val.toLowerCase()] = function(route, handler){
            /* _routePathIndex:    [ [], [], [], [], ]
               _routeMethodIndex:  [ [], [], [], [], ] */
            _routePathIndex[i].push(route);

            /* _routePathIndex:    [ ['/'], [], [], [], ]
               _routeMethodIndex:  [ ['/'], [], [], [], ] */
            _routeMethodIndex[i].push(handler);


            /* _routePathIndex:    [ ['/', [Function]], [], [], [], ]
               _routeMethodIndex:  [ ['/', [Function]], [], [], [], ] */
        }; 
...
```

---

**My question is, why is the array acting as tho there are referenced to each other?**

At first, I thought maybe it was the `.slice()` that was making the reference but I debunked that by running the following script in the same environment:

```
var a = [], b = a.slice();
a.push(1);
console.log(a,b); // [1] [0]
```

Another thing is when I don't do the `.slice()` trick and refactored the code to as such

```
...
    _routePathIndex = Array.apply(null, Array(METHODS.length)).map(() => {return []}),
    _routeMethodIndex = Array.apply(null, Array(METHODS.length)).map(() => {return []}),
```

the strange referencing behaviour is gone and the code works Perfect!

For added info I'm working with `node -v` : `v5.4.1`.

*Also I tried to clone the array using `[].concat(_routePathIndex)` but it still had that weird behaviour*

Comment: `Array.apply(null, Array(METHODS.length)).map(() => {return []})` seems (to me) a convoluted and unreadable way of writing `Array(METHODS.length).fill([])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`slice` only does a shallow copy, that is `_routePathIndex` and `_routeMethodIndex` are different, but their elements are the same. Consider this simplified example:

```js
a = [[],[]];
b = a.slice();
    
b[0].push(1);
document.write(a)
```

Get a picture:

[image]

Comment: can't accept answer too soon, SO rules, anyway what did you use to for the cool pic?

Comment: @jkris: http://merribithouse.net/arrows/ - developed this for my own use a while ago.